# Flutter/Dart QuerySnapshot isEqualTo or operator?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to ask if there is a document in the collection with the field "test" equal to 1 2 or 4. But unfortunately I have not found a suitable solution.

This is my approach Unfortunately, this does not work here (is Equal To 1 | 2 | 4). Is that no or operator? (|)

```
Future getPostsToday() async { 
   ...
    var firestore =  Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("Data").where("test",   isEqualTo: 1 | 2 | 4 ).getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;  
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> - Logical `OR` queries. In this case, you should create a separate query    for each `OR` condition and merge the query results in your
>     app.

Source: [Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

**Edit:**

So I think you could do something like this:

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getPostsToday() async {
  final collection = Firestore.instance.collection("Data");

  // separate query for each OR condition
  final querySnapshots = await Future.wait([
    collection.where("test", isEqualTo: 1).getDocuments(),
    collection.where("test", isEqualTo: 2).getDocuments(),
    collection.where("test", isEqualTo: 4).getDocuments(),
  ]);

  // merge the query results and return
  return <DocumentSnapshot>[
    ...querySnapshots[0].documents,
    ...querySnapshots[1].documents,
    ...querySnapshots[2].documents,
  ];
}
```

Comment: thanks but how could I implement this if there is no or operator?

Comment: getting error "Couldn't infer type parameter 'E'.

Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'E' which doesn't work:
  Return type declared as 'List<E>'
              used where  'List<Future<_>>' is required.
The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'element' declared as     'E'
                      but argument is 'dynamic'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic." any suggestion to fix it. Thanks.